# AWS CloudWatch Alarm Is Flaky Causing Many Falsified Triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

## Context

I'm using AWS IoT Core to communicate my edge sensors data into AWS cloud.
Every device has it's own unique topic, e.g., $aws/some_topic/DEVICE_ID/update, where it is reporting in an X minute interval (in my case, a telemetry is being sent every 20 minutes).

## Goal

I am trying to use AWS CloudWatch Alarm to monitor each sensor packet transmission separately. For this, I am taking advantage of the built-in TopicMatch Sum query over time, which does provide the amount of messages sent to the defined IoT topic, essentially indicating how many messages each edge device is sending.

## Problem

The alert is triggered very frequently, as shown in the image below:
[image: CloudWatch Flakiness]
notice the amount of red lines on the green bar. every red line is an alert being triggered.

I have tried several techniques to overcome this frequent alarm state changes, like aggregating data on a larger period of time, add data points tolerance and ignoring missing data, but with no luck.

It appears like CloudWatch looks on latest time-frame, which might be empty unless 20 minutes has passed, but I though the data aggregation into time buckets would've solve it.

Was hoping someone could shed some light on where exactly does this flakiness come from and how can I prevent it, ideally while keep using CloudWatch Alarms.

The query graph looks as follows (you can see, it is not breaching):
[image: query_graph]

And threshold configuration is like so:
[image: threshold_configuration]

Metrics view of the alert:
[image: metrics_view]

## I have tried:

- Using Anomaly Detection with wide/narrow bandwidth - still getting many alerts.
- decrease threshold to a very small number larger than zero ( in case there is an average somewhere).
- Increase data points to alarm (for instance, 5 out of 7 for 1 hour bucket) meaning 5 out of 7 hours the
  threshold was lower than 1 (which you can tell by the graph is not the case, yet alarms still triggers.
- Switch from Lower to Greater.
- changing Missing Data Treatment. (treat as missing, as bad, or ignore).

## Some Things I've Learnt on AWS CloudWatch Alarms While Debugging

- The graph might not always represent the actual reason the alarm has triggered, since it shape-shifting as time passes, so you might look see a perfectly fine graph with alerts being raised.
- Increasing data points are aimed to reduce flakiness and gain confidence in the decision, and does help, on some cases.
- AWS Documentation on treating missing data feature is quite vague.

Thank you in advance for any help.